# Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization (Spring Boot 2) - how to avoid actuator related fortify issue, or is it a false positive?

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, fortify

I am using the below actuator dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

with spring boot 2,

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Any comments on the fortify related vulnerabilities, or do we have any justifications for getting a false-positive regarding fortify issue.

Comment: Fortify check if the artifact does not contains any CVE. 
As you can see, Spring-boot 2.0.5(https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/12/spring-boot-2-0-5) announce a security update in the release.

So for Fortify this seems to be important to know which version of spring-boot you use to help it to consider as a FP or not

Comment: I am using Spring boot 2.1.2 and from the dependencies folder I see that it is using the Jackson 2.9.8 version, even then I am seeing same issue reported by Fortify for the line `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>` So it doesn't look like this is because of Jackson. Also Fortify is showing it as critical issue.

Comment: @VC2019 Same here.  Have you found a resolution for this yet?  Using Spring Boot 2.1.9 here.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by checking this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141809/forttify-dynamic-code-evaluation-unsafe-deserialization-on-spring-boot-actuator

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that the issue is being raised by Fortify not because of `spring-boot-starter-actuator` itself but its transitive dependency on Jackson which contains a [deserialization of untrusted data vulnerability](https://snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-COMFASTERXMLJACKSONCORE-72448). However, for an application to be vulnerable a non-default, and probably quite unusual, set of circumstances have to be true. You can learn more about those circumstances in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/on-jackson-cves-dont-panic-here-is-what-you-need-to-know-54cd0d6e8062) from Jackson's author. Spring Boot's Actuator does not enable polymorphic type handling so, if the Fortify warning is due to Jackson, it is a false positive.

The vulnerability has been [fixed](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/87d29af25e82a249ea15858e2d4ecbf64091db44) in Jackson 2.9.7 by blocking certain classes from polymorphic deserialisation. Spring Boot 2.0.6 and 2.1.0 use Jackson 2.9.7 by default.

Comment: Spring actuators are exposed via JMX and HTTP/JSON.  JVM had a Java deserialization vulnerability due to  `java.io.ObjectInputStream#readObject` instantiating the received class's name before throwing a class cast exception when the class does not extend the expected one.  The JRE's `java.security` now includes filter options, but I doubt deployments take care of that.  Would disabling Spring JMX endpoints work around the root cause in the mean time?  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-disable-jmx-endpoints

Comment: https://www.acunetix.com/blog/web-security-zone/old-java-libraries/